# How can I avoid that my Swift async method runs on the main thread in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency, task

I watched all the videos on async/await (and actors), but I am still confused a bit.

So assume I have an async method: `func postMessage(_ message: String) async throws` and I have a simple SwiftUI view.

```swift
@MainActor 
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var api = API()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Post Message") {
            Task {
                do {
                    try await api.postMessage("First post!")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I explicitly tell SwiftUI to use the `@MainActor` although I know it would have inferred from `@StateObject`.

To my understanding, since we use the `@MainActor` the work is done on the main thread. Meaning the work on Task would also be done on the main thread. Which is not what I want as the uploading process might take some while. In this case I could use `Task.detached` to use a different thread. Which would solve it. If my understanding is correct.

Now to make it a little more complicated. What if... postMessage would return a post identifier as an integer and I like to present that in the view?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var api = API()
    @State private var identifier: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Post Identifier: \(String(describing: identifier))")
        Button("Post Message") {
            Task {
                do {
                    identifier = try await api.postMessage("First post!")
                } catch {
                    identifier = 0
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would work as (again to my understanding) Task is run on the main thread. If I would change it now to `Task.detached` we will get an error `"Property 'identifier' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context"`.

Which makes sense, but how can we return the value to the main actor so the view can be updated?

Perhaps my assumptions are wrong. Let's look at my API class.

```swift
actor API {
    func postMessage(_ message: String) async throws -> Int {
        // Some complex internet code
        return 0
    }
}
```

Since the API runs in its own actor. Would the internet work also run on a different thread?

Comment: Inside `Task` is not run on Main Thread, because `await` will suspend current function

Comment: What stage of message posting is taking some while? Generating POST's body or network communication? If if's network communication then it's fine, main thread will not be blocked with it.

Comment: I am sorry if that was not clear. Yes the network communication could take some time. Just to be clear, if the API was just a class and not an actor itself, this would still 'cause no issues on the main thread because it awaits within Task right?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Comment: You should use `@MainActor` as a wrapper of your view model, no need to use it in your view. See also: "You can safely mutate state properties from any thread." in the [documentation](developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state).

Comment: I watched so many movies that's hard to keep track, but "Meet async/await" did cover what I was asking so I will use it in the answer.

Comment: @QuangHà - Minor clarification: `Task {…}` *is* isolated to the main actor. The [`body`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-8kl5o) is `@MainActor` and `Task {…}` simply creates a new top-level task on the main actor. Try breakpoint inside the `Task {…}` and note your are on the main thread. Or do something that is isolated to main actor and you will see that you are already on it. None of this is relevant to the OP’s question, because when you reach the `await` suspension point, the main actor is free to run other tasks while the api runs on its own actor. But, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Rob. The `Task { }` will inherit context of the caller.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question is very good, and answer is complex. I have spent significant time on this topic, for detailed information please follow the link to Apple developer forum in comments.

- All tasks mentioned below are unstructured tasks, eg. created by `Task ...`
- This is key: *"The main actor is an actor that represents the main thread. The main actor performs all of its synchronization through the main dispatch queue.*
- Unstructured tasks created by `Task.init` eg. `Task { ... }` inherit the actor async context.
- Detached tasks `Task.detached`, `async let =` tasks, group tasks do NOT inherit actor async context.
- Example 1: `let task1 = Task { () -> Void in ... }` creates and starts new task that inherits priority and async context from the point, where it is called. When created on the main thread, the task will run on the main thread.
- Example 2: `let task1 = Task.detached { () -> Void in ... }` creates and starts new task that does NOT inherit priority nor async context. The task will run on some thread, very likely on other thread than is the current thread. The executor decides that.
- Example 3: `let task1 = Task.detached { @MainActor () -> Void in ... }` creates and starts new task that does NOT inherit priority nor async context, but the task will run on the main thread, because it is annotated so.
- Very likely, the task will contain at least one `await` or `async let =` command. These commands are part of structured concurrency, and you cannot influence, on what thread are the implicitly created tasks (not discussed here at all) executed. The Swift executor decides that.
- The inherited actor async context has nothing to do with threads, after each `await` the thread may change, however the actor async context is kept throughout all the unstructured task (yes, may be on various threads, but this is important just for the executor).
- If the inherited actor async context is MainActor, then the task runs on the main thread, from beginning till its end, because the actor context is MainActor. This is important if you plan to run some really parallel computation - make sure all the unstructured tasks do not run on the same thread.
- ContentView is on @MainActor in both the cases: in the first case is it @MainActor explicitely, the second case uses @StateObject property wrapper that is @MainActor, so the whole ContentView structure is @MainActor inferred. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/understanding-how-global-actor-inference-works
- `async let =`  is a structured concurrency, it does not inherit actor async context, and runs in parallel immediately, as scheduled by the executor (on some other thread, if available)
- The example on top has one system flaw: `@StateObject private var api = API()` is @MainActor. This is forced by the @StateObject. So, I would recommend to inject other actor with other actor async context as a dependency without @StateObject. The async/await will really work, keeping await calls with the proper actor contexts.

Comment: You can also check https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710646

Comment: A minor refinement: You say “All tasks mentioned below are unstructured tasks, eg. created by `Task …`”. But, you then proceed to provide examples of both structured and unstructured concurrency. E.g., you correctly point that the task created by `async let` is structured concurrency. You also make a passing reference to task groups, and that also is structured concurrency. So, yes, `Task { … }` and `Task.detached { … }` are unstructured concurrency, but neither `async let` nor task groups are.

Comment: You say: `async let = tasks, group tasks do NOT inherit actor async context.`. Documentations says - async let creates a child task implicitly. Documentation also says - child tasks inherit context from their parent. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: @Petar I wrote `async let =  is a structured concurrency, it does not inherit actor async context`. I also wrote `Detached tasks Task.detached, async let = tasks, group tasks do NOT inherit actor async context.` These are 2 separate sentences, please note the commas, they are important. The key point, not too much discussed anywhere, is the fact that child task and async context inheritance are two **separate** topics. The fact that some task inherits async context does not mean, it is a child task! This comment has limited number of characters to discuss it in depth.

Comment: @MichaelBernat Would love to move the convo in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256330/swift-concurrency if okay with you

Answer (score 8):

You said:

> To my understanding, since we use the `@MainActor` the work is done on the main thread. Meaning the work on `Task` would also be done on the main thread. Which is not what I want as the uploading process might take some while.

Just because the uploading process (a) might take some time; and (b) was invoked from the main actor, that does *not* mean that the main thread will be blocked while the request is performed.

In fact, this is the whole point of Swift concurrency’s `await`. It frees the current thread to go do other things while we `await` results from the called routine. Do not conflate the `await` of Swift concurrency (which will not block the calling thread) with the various `wait` constructs of traditional GCD patterns (which will).

E.g., consider the following code launched from the main actor:

```swift
Task {
    do {
        identifier = try await api.postMessage("First post!")
    } catch {
        identifier = 0
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Yes, because you used `Task` and invoked it from the main actor, that code will also run on the main actor. Thus, `identifier` will be updated on the main actor. But it says nothing about which actor/queue/thread that `postMessage` is using. The `await` keyword means “I'll suspend this path of execution, and let the main thread and go do other things while we `await` the `postMessage` initiating its network request and its eventual response.”

You asked:

> Let's look at my API class.
>
> ```swift
> actor API {
>     func postMessage(_ message: String) async throws -> Int {
>         // Some complex internet code
>
>         return 0
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Since the API runs in its own actor. Would the internet work also run
> on a different thread?

As a general rule, networking libraries perform their requests asynchronously, not blocking the threads from which they are called. Assuming the “complex internet code” follows this standard convention, you then you simply do not have to worry about what thread it is running on. The actor’s thread will not be blocked while the request runs.

Taking this a step further, the fact that the `API` is its own actor is immaterial to the question. Even if `API` was on the main actor, because the network request runs asynchronously, whatever the thread used by `API` will not be blocked.

(NB: The above assumes that the “complex internet code” has followed conventional asynchronous network programming patterns. We obviously cannot comment further without seeing a representative example of this code.)

---

See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/) if you are interested in how Swift concurrency manages threads for us.

Answer (score 2):

The `Task` is the bridge between the Async and the Synchronous world. The completion block of `Button` being the synchronous world and the `postMessage` method as being the asynchronous world.

The `Task` is run on the `@MainActor` however since we `await` the result of `api.postMessage` it may suspend and the main thread is not blocked.

*Thanks to Quang Hà and Lorem Ipsum.*

---

**Useful information regarding this question from WWDC.**

From [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=444) (Timecode - 7:24)

*To update correctly, SwiftUI needs these events to happen in order: objectWillChange, the ObservableObject’s state is updated, and then the run loop reaches its next tick. If I can ensure that these all happen on the main actor, I can guarantee this ordering. Prior to Swift 5.5, I might have dispatched back to the main queue to update my state, but now it’s much easier. Just use await! By using await to make an async call from the main actor, I let other work continue on the main actor while the async work happens. This is called “yielding” the main actor.*

From [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/?time=1333) (Timecode - 22:13):

*The solution is to use the async task function. An async task packages up the work in the closure and sends it to the system for immediate execution on the next available thread, like the async function on a global dispatch queue.*

From [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=442) (Timecode - 7:25)

*If the actor is busy, then your code will suspend so that the CPU you're running on can do other useful work. When the actor becomes free again, it will wake up your code -- resuming execution -- so the call can run on the actor. The await keyword in this example indicates that the asynchronous call to the actor might involve such a suspension.*

From [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=1408) (Timecode - 23:47)

*When you are building an app, you need to think about the main thread. It is where the core user interface rendering happens, as well as where user interaction events are processed. Operations that work with the UI generally need to be performed from the main thread. However, you don't want to do all of your work on the main thread. If you do too much work on the main thread, say, because you have some slow input/output operation or blocking interaction with a server, your UI will freeze. So, you need to be careful to do work on the main thread when it interacts with the UI but get off the main thread quickly for computationally expensive or long-waiting operations. So, we do work off the main thread when we can and then call DispatchQueue.main.async in your code whenever you have a particular operation that must be executed on the main thread.*

*If you know you're already running on the main thread, you can safely access and update your UI state. If you aren't running on the main thread, you need to interact with it asynchronously. This is exactly how actors work.*

*The main actor is an actor that represents the main thread. It differs from a normal actor. The main actor performs all of its synchronization through the main dispatch queue. This means that, from a runtime perspective, the main actor is interchangeable with using DispatchQueue.main.*

Comment: I wouldn’t trust that meet async in SwiftUI video too much. I mean look at the await spacePhoto.save() the girl does near end of video that is complete nonsense!

Comment: Other then she is using async instead of Task could you collaborate what is complete nonsense?

Comment: At 11:54 in the auto-complete we can see that SpacePhoto is a struct, we also see its init with data, its not given any handle to a controller. At 15:38 we see PhotoView has a var SpacePhoto, not a binding, which means it isn't mutable, yet at 18:36 we see photo.save() so what on earth is that doing?

Comment: @malhal - You overstate your case: 1. “`SpacePhoto` is ... not given any handle to a controller”. ... Model objects should not be tightly coupled with controllers! 2. The `photo.save()` is likely just saving the photo to your local photo library and the mutability is irrelevant. Don't get me wrong, there _are_ lots of trivial mistakes in their code (found in Developer app) E.g., they build URLs incorrectly; the date formatter should specify a locale, no working endpoint, etc.). But the basic patterns/ideas in this video are perfectly valid, IMHO. Don't throw the baby out with the bath water.