# Difference of creating regular or detached Task from task-less context?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

When creating a `Task` in a task-less context (e.g. from some random `AppKit` code), is there a difference between creating a detached or a regular task? For example, calling

- `Task.detached`
- or `Task.init`

Since the task has no actor to inherit from, I figured those 2 calls must be equivalent or are there still implementation differences to consider?

Comment: Umm... neither of those create a child task?

Comment: If you create a `Task` inside an existing task, it will be the child of that one. Otherwise there would be no point to `Task.detached`.

Comment: [That's not what the documentation says...](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856791-init) "Run given operation as asynchronously in its own *top-level* task." `Task.init` copies over the current priority and actor context (`detached` does not). Child tasks do that too, but that doesn't mean `Task.init` create child tasks. `await someAsyncFunc()` and `async let` etc are what create child tasks.

Comment: `inherits the priority and actor context of the caller` -> ergo: "child" task. Also tasks created with `Task.init` are cancelled when the parent is cancelled unlike `detached` tasks.

Comment: Era, it sounds like you understand the difference, so I'm not sure if I understand your question. IMHO, detached tasks are designed to solve a very specific problem, to opt the task out of structured concurrency and/or get it off the current thread. I would only do this when I need these specific behaviors, and otherwise use `Task.init`. Using detached tasks unnecessarily seems imprudent. But where needed, then certainly use it. The threading behaviors of the two are different, so I would not consider them equivalent.

Comment: Thats why I am asking, because it is not documented if it makes a difference if used from a context without a specific actor. So the real question I guess is, if any regular thread has an implicit actor.

Comment: Understood. A data point from my empirical tests: If I initiate a `Task { … }` and `Task.detached { … }` from a non-swift-concurrency random background GCD worker thread, it behaves as if it were initiated from the main actor (namely that the former runs on the main thread and the latter on a background thread, regardless). So it’s not a function of the thread from which you initiate it, but some other, broader context. My suspicion is that an app just runs on the main actor by default (though, I confess, I have not yet found the relevant explicit `@MainActor` decoration in the headers)…

Comment: I summarized my findings in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73015435/8220920

Answer (score 13):

First of all, it is important to note that neither of these create child tasks. A child task is created by [structured](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) concurrency constructs like `async let`, task groups etc, as opposed to unstructured concurrency like `Task.init` and `Task.detached`.

> In addition to the structured approaches to concurrency described in the previous sections, Swift also supports unstructured concurrency. [...] To create an unstructured task that runs on the current actor, call the `Task.init(priority:operation:)` initializer. To create an unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor, known more specifically as a detached task, call the `Task.detached(priority:operation:)` class method.

This is also documented in [`Task.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856791-init) (my bold)

> Runs the given nonthrowing operation asynchronously as part of a new **top-level task** on behalf of the current actor.

You can also see this in action - a child task created by `async let` is cancelled when its parent is cancelled, but a task created by `Task.init` is not.

```
let task = Task {
    let notChild = Task {
        await Task.sleep(1_000_000_000)
        if !Task.isCancelled {
            print("Not Child!")
        } else {
            print("Child!")
        }
    }
}
task.cancel()
// prints "Not Child!"
```

```
func childTask() async {
    await Task.sleep(1_000_000_000)
    if !Task.isCancelled {
        print("Not Child!")
    } else {
        print("Child!")
    }
}

let task = Task {
    async let x = childTask()
}
task.cancel()
// prints "Child!"
```

Anyway, back to your question, so what actually is the difference between `Task.init` and `Task.detached`? The first quote in my answer addressed that a little bit, and this is also mentioned in the documentation of `Task.init` too:

> Like `Task.detached(priority:operation:)`, this function creates a separate, top-level task. Unlike `Task.detached(priority:operation:)`, the task created by `Task.init(priority:operation:)` **inherits the priority and actor context of the caller**, so the operation is treated more like an asynchronous extension to the synchronous operation.

Essentially, it's about the *actor* on which the task is executed, so even if there is no current task, but there is a current actor, `Task.init` and `Task.detached` will still do different things. `Task.init` will run the task on the current actor, whereas `Task.detached` will run the task detached from any actor.

See also: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/whats-the-difference-between-a-task-and-a-detached-task

Comment: As I said, you did not understand what I was asking... this is not it. I was asking what difference `Task.init` and `Task.detached` makes coming from a **task-less** (toplevel) context.

Comment: @Era I did understand that part, yes. And I also addressed that part in the last paragraph. Whether you have a current task doesn’t matter as much as you think. It’s about the actor.

Comment: So there is basically no difference, since 99.9% of top level contexts are NOT actors. Or are you saying that creating a `Task` e.g. in `NSApplicationDelegate.applicationWillFinishLaunching` will refer to the main actor? What happens if a task is created on a random `DispatchQueue`?

Comment: @Era I would imagine that most of the time (this is from my experience) the main actor would be running the code. In other words, the code would be running on the main queue. Keep in mind that there are global actors!

Comment: This logic doesn't work for e.g. callbacks on a random global `DispatchQueue`. What actor would anyone expect there? This whole system is not thought through...

Comment: In any case, the answer is still irrelevant to my quesiton. Since we don't know what actor is used, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Such a good answer @Sweeper

Comment: Sweeper, can you please explain "Unstructured tasks created with the Task initializer inherit important metadata information from the context in which it is created, including priority, task-local values, and actor isolation." from https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md#context-inheritance - if your task is created in an actor - why wouldn't that mean that notChild is not running on that actor as well ? Also in all the resources I've found I never saw anywhere being mentioned that `await` creates a child task - only that it will suspend ?

Comment: @Petar "why wouldn't that mean that notChild is not running on that actor as well ?" The double negative here is rather confusing... `notChild` will run on the same actor too, since `Task.init` inherits the actor context. Did I claim otherwise? And you are right, I couldn't find anywhere that says `await` creates child tasks either. The behaviour is really similar and I got confused. Finally I'm not sure what you don't understand about that quote. I would suggest posting a new question, and make it very clear what you don't understand.

Comment: Sweeper, also can you please explain (with a real example) why would someone create an instance of Task inside another Task ? This contradicts everything I've read so far on the topic

Comment: @Petar I don't know why someone would do that either. In the comments, OP [claimed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575803/difference-of-creating-regular-or-detached-task-from-task-less-context/71577170?noredirect=1#comment126502998_71575803) that `Task.init` creates a child task when nested inside another `Task`. I was just addressing that comment.

Comment: This is just so confusing, I cannot comprehend how the Swift team made it sound so easy yet when one actually tries to understand what is going on it is very hard.... `async let` creates a child task(you have no notion of tasks here and task creation is implicit). Initializing Task is not a child task. They are both called Task, and probably use the same component but they work differently.  Rant over :D