# `Task` blocks main thread when calling async function inside

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, swift-concurrency

I have an `ObservableObject` class and a SwiftUI view. When a button is tapped, I create a [`Task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) and call `populate` (an async function) from within it. I thought this would execute `populate` on a background thread but instead the entire UI freezes. Here's my code:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [String]()
    func populate() async {
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 { /// this usually takes a couple seconds
            items.append("\(i)")
        }
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ViewModel()
    @State var rotation = CGFloat(0)

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {
                await model.populate()
            }
        } label: {
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
                .overlay(
                    Text("\(model.items.count)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
        }
        .onAppear { /// should be a continuous rotation effect
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever()) {
                rotation = 90
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Rotation animation freezes when the button is pressed]

The button stops moving, then suddenly snaps back when `populate` finishes.

Weirdly, if I move the `Task` into `populate` itself and get rid of the `async`, the rotation animation doesn't stutter so I think the loop actually got executed in the background. However I now get a `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed` warning.

```
func populate() {
    Task {
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 {
            items.append("\(i)")
        }
        self.items = items /// Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
    }
}

/// ...

Button {
    model.populate()
}
```

Result:

[image: Rotation animation continues even when the button is pressed]

How can I ensure my code gets executed on a background thread? I think this might have something to do with `MainActor` but I'm not sure.

Comment: `await` means that you wait for the `async` function to return you a result (which obviously blocks the current thread, which is main). In your second option you run the task on a background thread, so you need to ensure that results of the task are delivered to the main thread. The error you see hints you about this and provides an example, how to achieve this. How do you deliver items to the UI? Is it just a property on an observable object?

Comment: @lazarevzubov but aren't `Task`s asynchronous? When I `await` inside a `Task` shouldn't  the current thread be a background thread? I can't figure out the difference between the first and second options. Anyway in SwiftUI all you need to do is set the property and the UI automatically updates.

Comment: Have you tried to use in your second option `MainActor.run { self.items = items }` to move the update to the main thread?

Comment: Task should be detached and a function performing published property modification is wrapped with MainActor - [possible solution is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Task_blocks_main_thread.md)

Comment: @lazarevzubov I tried that, but I get `Reference to captured var 'items' in concurrently-executing code`

Comment: I summarized my findings in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73015435/8220920

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First, as a general observation, in WWDC 2021’s [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290), they recommend that you isolate the [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/) object to the main actor.

But the hitch in the UI is caused by the main actor being blocked by this slow process. So we must get this task off the main actor. There are a few possible approaches:

1. You can move the slow synchronous process to a “detached” task. While [`Task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) starts a new top-level task “on behalf of the current actor”, a detached task is an “unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor”. So, [`detached`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-3lvix) task will avoid blocking the current actor:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var items = [String]()

       func populate() async {
           let task = Task.detached {
               var items: [String] = []

               for i in 0 ..< .random(in: 4_000_000...5_000_000) { // made it random so I could see values change
                   items.append("\(i)")
               }
               return items
           }

           items = await task.value
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, while this solves the blocking problem, unfortunately, `Task.detached {…}` (like `Task {…}`) is *[unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency).* So, this is probably not a pattern I would generally recommend (unless you wrap it in an `withTaskCancellationHandler`). But see more on cancelation under point 4, below.
2. As of Swift 5.7, one can achieve the same behavior with an `async` function that is `nonisolated` (see [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md)). And this keeps us within the realm of structured concurrency, but still gets the work off the current actor:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var items = [String]()

       private nonisolated func generate() async -> [String] {
           var items: [String] = []

           for i in 0 ..< .random(in: 4_000_000...5_000_000) { // made it random so I could see values change
               items.append("\(i)")
           }
           return items
       }

       func populate() async {
           items = await generate()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Or we can do this with a separate `actor` for the time-consuming process, which again gets the task off the view model’s actor:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var items = [String]()
       private let generator = Generator()

       private actor Generator {
           func generate() async -> [String] {
               var items: [String] = []

               for i in 0 ..< .random(in: 4_000_000...5_000_000) { // made it random so I could see values change
                   items.append("\(i)")
               }
               return items
           }
       }

       func populate() async {
           items = await generator.generate()
       }
   }
   ```
4. I would advise adding cancelation logic (in case the user wants to interrupt the calculation and start another) with `try Task.checkCancellation()`.

   Also, in Swift concurrency, we should never violate the contract to “ensure forward progress”, or, if you must, periodically [`Task.yield`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/yield()/) to ensure proper function of this concurrency system. As [SE-0296](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md) says:

   > Because potential suspension points can only appear at points explicitly marked within an asynchronous function, long computations can still block threads. This might happen when calling a synchronous function that just does a lot of work, or when encountering a particularly intense computational loop written directly in an asynchronous function. In either case, the thread cannot interleave code while these computations are running, which is usually the right choice for correctness, but can also become a scalability problem. Asynchronous programs that need to do intense computation should generally run it in a separate context. When that’s not feasible, there will be library facilities to artificially suspend and allow other operations to be interleaved.

   Now, the previously mentioned techniques (points 1-3, above) address your primary concern by prevent the blocking of the main actor. But the deeper observation here is that we really should avoid blocking *any* actors with “long running” work. But  [`Task.yield`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/yield()/) addresses that problem.

   Anyway, considering the `nonisolated` example, we can handle cancelation and interleaving with:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var items = [String]()

       private nonisolated func generate() async throws -> [String] {
           var items = [String]()
           for i in 0 ..< .random(in: 4_000_000 ... 5_000_000) {
               if i.isMultiple(of: 1000) {
                   await Task.yield()
                   try Task.checkCancellation()
               }
               items.append("\(i)")
           }
           try Task.checkCancellation()
           return items
       }

       func populate() async throws {
           items = try await generate()
       }
   }
   ```

   Or the `actor` approach would follow the same pattern:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var items = [String]()
       private let generator = Generator()

       private actor Generator {
           func generate() async throws -> [String] {
               var items = [String]()
               for i in 0 ..< .random(in: 4_000_000 ... 5_000_000) {
                   if i.isMultiple(of: 1000) {
                       await Task.yield()
                       try Task.checkCancellation()
                   }
                   items.append("\(i)")
               }
               try Task.checkCancellation()
               return items
           }
       }

       func populate() async throws {
           items = try await generator.generate()
       }
   }
   ```

   This periodic checking for cancelation and yielding is only needed when writing our own computationally intensive tasks. Most of Apple‘s `async` API (e.g. `URLSession`, etc.), already handle these issues for us.

   Anyway, all of this discussion on cancelation begs the question of how one would go about canceling a prior task. Simply save the `Task` in a property of the actor-isolated view model and then cancel the prior one before starting the next. E.g.:

   ```swift
   private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

   func start() {
       task?.cancel()                         // cancel prior one, if any
       task = Task { try await populate() }
   }
   ```

Anyway, these patterns will allow the slow process to not block the main thread, resulting in an uninterrupted UI. Here I tapped on the button twice:

[image]

Needless to say, that is without the “cancel prior one” logic. With that logic, you can tap multiple times, all the prior once will be canceled, and you will see only one update, avoiding potentially over taxing the system with a bunch of redundant tasks. But the idea is the same, an smooth UI while performing complex tasks.

---

See WWDC 2021 videos [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/), [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133), and [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194), all of which are useful when trying to grok the transition from GCD to Swift concurrency.

Answer (score 11):

**Update 6/10/22:** At WWDC I asked some Apple engineers about this problem — it really is all about actor inheritance. However, there were some compiler-level changes in Xcode 14 Beta. For example, this will run smoothly on Xcode 14, but lag on Xcode 13:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [String]()

    func populate() async {
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 { /// this usually takes a couple seconds
            items.append("\(i)")
        }

        /// explicitly capture `items` to avoid `Reference to captured var 'items' in concurrently-executing code; this is an error in Swift 6`
        Task { @MainActor [items] in
            self.items = items
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ViewModel()
    @State var rotation = CGFloat(0)

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {

                /// *Note!* Executes on a background thread in Xcode 14.
                await self.model.populate()
            }
        } label: {
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
                .overlay(
                    Text("\(model.items.count)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
        }
        .onAppear { /// should be a continuous rotation effect
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever()) {
                rotation = 90
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, `Task` inherits the context of where it's called.

- A `Task` called from within a plain `ObservableObject` class will run in the background, since the class isn't a main actor.
- A `Task` called inside a `Button` will probably run on the main actor, since the `Button` is a UI element. *Except, Xcode 14 changed some things and it actually runs in the background too...*

To make sure a function runs on the background thread, independent of the inherited actor context, you can add `nonisolated`.

```
nonisolated func populate() async {

}
```

Note: the [Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110350/) video is super helpful.

Comment: Re "Xcode 14 changed some things and it actually runs in the background too", how to know for sure?  I tried Thread.isMainThread, but it says "Class property isMainThread is unavailable from asynchronous contexts." If a Task is running asynchronously but in the MainActor context, a UI `@State` var can be updated directly, but if the Task is on a different thread, then the `@State` var needs to be updated on the main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async or a `@MainActor` decorator on the `@State` var itself, correct? Or you will get the purple warning about an update on a background thread.

Comment: Not that sure — that's what the Apple engineer told me...

Comment: Interesting! I'm sure it's right then. I wish they had more documentation about it. Maybe the docs will get better over time.

Comment: I have tested the OPs code. It runs on the background thread. Task will do a dispatch to the background.

Comment: @JamesToomey - I suspect the engineer was referencing [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md), where they formalized that non-isolated `async` methods do not run on any particular actor.

Comment: @aheze - Just to be precise, where you state “Executes on a background thread in Xcode 14” might be misleading. That `Task {…}` *is* on the main actor. It is `populate` which doesn’t run on the current actor. Maybe that’s what you were trying to say, but just a clarification for future readers.

Comment: Yes, we can't ensure anything undocumented. The only safe way is mark `nonisolated` at the function should be run in background thread we expect.

Comment: @JamesToomey check my thread below. In Xcode 14, it does run in background thread

Comment: @LiangWang Thanks for posting that! Good to know.

Answer (score 9):

First, you can't have it both ways; Either you perform your CPU intensive work on the main thread (and have a negative impact on the UI) or you perform the work on another thread, but you need to explicitly dispatch the UI update onto the main thread.

However, what you are really asking about is

> (By using `Task`) I thought this would execute populate on a background thread but instead the entire UI freezes.

When you use a `Task` you are using [*unstructured concurrency*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642), and when you initialise your `Task` via [init(priority:operation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856790-init) *the task ... inherits the priority and actor context of the caller*.

While the `Task` is executed asynchronously, it does so using the actor context of the caller, which in the context of a `View` `body` is the main actor.  This means that while your task is executed asynchronously, it still runs on the main thread and that thread is not available for UI updates while it is processing.  So you are correct, this has everything to do with `MainActor`.

When you move the `Task` into `populate` it is no longer being created in a `MainActor` context and therefore does not execute on the main thread.

As you have discovered, you need to use this second approach to avoid the main thread.  All you need to do to your code is move the final update back to the main queue using the `MainActor`:

```
func populate() {
    Task {
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 {
            items.append("\(i)")
        }
        await MainActor.run {
            self.items = items 
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `Task.detached()` in the body context to create a `Task` that is not attached the `MainActor` context.

Comment: Thanks, that part about inheriting the context makes sense. But about the `DispatchQueue.main.async {`, I heard that you shouldn't mix async/await with the old stuff, do you know if there's any impact? I also tried replacing `Task` with `Task.detached` and nothing happened.

Comment: Correct, see my update

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, the reason of this behavior is that the `Task.init` inherits the actor context automatically. You're calling your function from the button callback:

```
Button {
    Task {
        await model.populate()
    }
} label: {

}
```

The button callback is on the main actor, so the closure passed to the `Task` initializer is on the main actor too.

One solution is using a detached task:

```
func populate() async {
    Task.detached {
        // Calculation here
    }
}
```

While detached tasks are unstructured, I'd like to suggest structured tasks like `async let` tasks:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [String]()

    func populate() async {
        async let newItems = { () -> [String] in
            var items = [String]()
            for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 {
                items.append("\(i)")
            }
            return items
        }()

        items = await newItems
    }
}
```

This is useful when you want the `populate` function to return some value asynchronously. This structured task approach also means cancellation can be propagated automatically. For example, if you want to cancel the calculation when the button is tapped multiple times in a short time, you can do something like this:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [String]()

    func populate() async {
        async let newItems = { () -> [String] in
            var items = [String]()
            for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 {
                // Stop in the middle if cancelled
                if i % 1000 == 0 && Task.isCancelled {
                    break
                }
                items.append("\(i)")
            }
            return items
        }()

        items = await newItems
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model: ViewModel
    @State var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    init() {
        _model = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            task?.cancel() // Cancel previous task if any
            task = Task {
                await model.populate()
            }
        } label: {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, `withTaskGroup` also creates structured tasks and you can avoid inheriting the actor context too. It can be useful when your computation has multiple child tasks that can progress concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 14, Task{} does run in the background thread for the above example. Let me prove it.

To be highlighted, Adding `@MainActor` will make sure it runs on the main thread.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing the class. You aren't using Combine so you don't need its `ObservableObject` and SwiftUI is most efficient if you stick to value types. The button doesn't hang with this design:

```
extension String {
    static func makeItems() async -> [String]{
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 0 ..< 4_000_000 { /// this usually takes a couple seconds
            items.append("\(i)")
        }
        return items
    }
}

struct AnimateContentView: View {
    @State var rotation = CGFloat(0)
    @State var items = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {
                items = await String.makeItems()
            }
        } label: {
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
                .overlay(
                    Text("\(items.count)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
        }
        .onAppear { /// should be a continuous rotation effect
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever()) {
                rotation = 90
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How come the class causes problems though? I would prefer to keep it for the code organization and ability to share state with UIKit

Comment: you can use custom structs for that

Comment: @aheze There's nothing wrong with using classes for what you're doing. Feel free to use them.