ProgressView Not Updating During Data Parsing in SwiftUI
It's hard to reproduce the full code, but I'll try to explain the issue clearly.
I'm trying to display a progress bar view to show the status of parsing some data downloaded online. The function I use for parsing correctly prints the download percentage in the console, but for some reason, my progress view doesn't update.
The downloadData function has an escaping closure to report the stages of the download (downloadData, parseData, savingData).
When downloading data, the ProgressView updates correctly. However, when the downloadStage is in the parseData stage, nothing updates in the view. I see the ProgressView says "Parsing Data," but the value doesn't change. The console prints the data, so I’m sure the data is correctly passed into the view.
What could be the issue?
I've noticed that if I insert a small delay in my code, the ProgressView updates. How can I ensure the view updates correctly?

  // MARK: - Download Data
    func downloadData(lista: PlayListModel, completion: @escaping (_ stage: DownloadStage, _ progress: Double, _ total: Int) -> Void) async throws {
        
        
        do {
            var m3uString = ""
            // RUN as 1st
            m3uString = try await requestM3UListAlamo(from: lista.playlistUrl, progressHandler: { progress in
                
                completion(.downloadData, progress, 100)
                
            })
            
            completion(.parseData, 0, 0)
// At this point func don't update the UI 
            let group = try await sdparsePlaylist(m3uContent: m3uString) { progress, total in
                completion(.parseData, progress, Int(total))
            }
            
            completion(.savingData, 0.0, 0)
            
            try await saveData(lista: lista, grouped: group) { stage, result in
                
                completion(stage, 100, 100)

            }
            
            
        } catch {
            
            // Handle failure and update completion stage
            print("Download failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(.fail, 0, 0)
            
            throw error // Propagate error to caller
        }
    }
    

  func sdparsePlaylist(m3uContent: String, completion: @escaping (_ progress: Double, _ total: Int) -> Void) async throws -> [String: [PlaylistItem]] {
        print("4-------------- parsing playlist --------------")
        var appoggio: [String: [PlaylistItem]] = [:]
        let createDate = Date()

        do {
            let playlist = try await self.parser.parse(m3uContent)
            let media = playlist.medias
            let totalItems = media.count
            var progress = 0
            
            for item in media {
                let attributes = item.attributes
                let groupTitle = attributes.groupTitle ?? "NOT CLASSIFIED"
                let playlistItem = PlaylistItem(duration: item.duration, tvgId: attributes.id, tvgName: attributes.name, tvgCountry: attributes.country, tvgLanguage: attributes.language, tvgLogo: attributes.logo, tvgChno: attributes.channelNumber, tvgShift: attributes.shift, groupTitle: groupTitle, seasonNumber: attributes.seasonNumber, episodeNumber: attributes.episodeNumber, kind: item.kind.rawValue, url: item.url, lastPlay: createDate)
                
                if var existingPlaylist = appoggio[groupTitle] {
                    existingPlaylist.append(playlistItem)
                    appoggio[groupTitle] = existingPlaylist
                } else {
                    appoggio[groupTitle] = [playlistItem]
                }
                
                
                let currentProgress = Double(progress) / Double(totalItems) * 100
                completion(currentProgress, 100)
                print("parser background: \(currentProgress)% (\(progress + 1) / \(totalItems))")
                progress += 1
                
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            throw error
        }
       
        return appoggio
    }


The View:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import Alamofire

struct AddNewPlaylist: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State private var playlistName = "TV"
@State private var playlistUrl = "https://country.m3u"

    
    @State var downloadStage: DownloadStage = .none
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State var total = 0
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var bounce = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    let backgroundParser: BackgroundParser
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Add New Playlist")
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Text1"))
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            TextField("Playlist Name", text: $playlistName)
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1))
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Text1"))
            TextField("M3U Link", text: $playlistUrl)
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1))
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Text1"))
                .overlay {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        if !playlistUrl.isEmpty {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.playlistUrl = "" // Clear the text
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                            .padding(.trailing, 8)
                        }
                    }
                }
            HStack {
                Button {
                    Task {
                        await backgroundParser.cancelDownload()
                        isPresented = false
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Return")
                }
                .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Text1"))
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Save") {
                    if playlistName != "" && playlistUrl != "" {
                        Task {
                            do {
                                let playlist = PlayListModel(timestamp: Date(), playlistName: playlistName, playlistUrl: playlistUrl, lastUpdate: Date())
                                try await backgroundParser.downloadData(lista: playlist) { stage, prog, total in
                                    // print correcctly but the view dont update
                                    print("going tp update \(stage.description), \(prog), \(total)")
                                    self.downloadStage = stage
                                    self.progress = prog
                                    self.total = total
                                    
                                    if stage == .done {
                                        isPresented = false
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            } catch {
                                    alertMessage = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                    showAlert = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
                .foregroundStyle(Color("Text1"))
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 50)
            
            Spacer()
            
            
            VStack{
                switch downloadStage {
                    
                case .downloadData:
                
                    ProgressView(value: progress, total: CGFloat(total)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Downloading Data...").font(.title3)
                            Text("\(Int(progress)) / \(total)")
                        }
                    }.progressViewStyle(.linear)
                    
                case .parseData:
                    // Here no work --------------------------------------
                    ProgressView(value: progress, total: 100) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Parsing Data...").font(.title3)
                            Text("\(Int(progress)) / \(total)")
                        }
                    }.progressViewStyle(.linear)
                
                case .savingData:
                        HStack {
                            Text("Saving data...don't close window").font(.title3)
                           
                        }
                default:
                    
                    Text("")
                }
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
            
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.color1, .color2, .color3], startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .topTrailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}




completion handles are not compatible with async/await you have to convert all of them watch "Meet async/await"

Yes, you can’t really combine usage of the async/await syntax, you should pick one or the other. If you want to convert the completion handlers to async functions you could use continuations which have been masterfully documented by Nick

“What could be the issue?” … It sounds like you are blocking the main thread. If you profile the app in Instruments (say, with the “Time Profiler” template), you can configure the “Hangs” tool to use a “Reporting threshold” of either 500, 250, 100, or 33 msec, to help identify these issues. In terms of resolving it, get the parsing and saving off the main thread. E.g., make the parser an actor or isolate to some global actor other than @MainActor. Likewise, if saving via SwiftData, you can use a ModelActor to get your moc off of the main thread.

Your completion handler execute code in the Task thread. Put the completion code block in a dispatch main async.

Indiscriminate asynchronous dispatching to the main queue was the precise source of the problem in Damiano’s previous question. And that doesn’t solve the likely problem here, namely that he’s blocking the main thread. Besides, closures for progress updates are a bit of an anti-pattern, anyway. Better to use an asynchronous sequence or observed property.

Your for item in media loop doesn't contain any await, meaning it's synchronous and there are no suspension points at which the UI can be updated. Try adding await Task.yield() within the loop.
Update
A better solution would be to get sdparsePlaylist and downloadData off the main actor where UI updates happen.

Set Strict Concurrency Checking to Complete in the Xcode build settings. This will help you identify programming errors.
sdparsePlaylist appears to be isolated to the main actor based on the problem you are facing. You want to get it off the main actor to not block the UI. If it is in a class isolated to the main actor, remove @MainActor or make it a nonisolated func.
All parameters and return values of your nonisolated async function must be Sendable because the concurrency context can change. If using Sendable is not practical because you are passing SwiftData models around then use a ModelActor instead. If you need some other non-Sendable state, use an actor.


IMHO, Task.yield is intended for a more general problem, namely to avoid blocking any thread from the Swift concurrency cooperative thread pool. If you’ve got work blocking the main thread, you should just get it off the main thread, altogether, rather than blocking the main thread and periodically yielding…

@Rob Sounds good in theory but I've had Task.detached(priority: .background) block my app with synchronous code without Task.yield.

@Rob I cannot reproduce it in a simple example though. Getting the work off the main actor is a good idea anyway, will surely work in this case and is a cleaner solution. If you don't post an answer I might add it as an alternative.

yield() is for a pretty narrow use-case (see point 4 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71876683/1271826). So, first, we never block the main thread. But, even when off the main thread, we must use yield when we’ve got a slow, synchronous, long-running task on a thread from the cooperative thread pool (or just get it out of Swift concurrency system, altogether). We must honor our contract to never impede forward progress in Swift concurrency. If you’ve only got one background task, failing to yield is not immediately catastrophic, but you can introduce deadlocks if you’ve got a lot of them.

Re getting it off the main thread, Task.detached is one pattern (but, as unstructured concurrency, you then have to manually handle cancelation, e.g., using withTaskCancellationHandler). Using an actor or non-isolated async function are easier ways of getting it off the main actor while still enjoying structured concurrency. But feel free to update your answer with these alternatives. I only hesitated to post an answer myself because Damiano hasn’t shared a MRE, making all of this unnecessarily confusing…
